# Upgrade to Grails 2.4.4 : /index.gsp not found

Tags: grails

In Grails 1.0.3 version shows the list of controllers, when the url is placed in the browser. But currently its giving /index.gsp not found.
class UrlMappings {

```
    static mappings = {
        "/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
        "/"(view:"/index")
        "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

This is my urlMappings.groovy. Please give me the solution to avoid this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your url mapping you have `"/"(view:"/index")`, which means in Grails 2.4.4 that it's calling gsp view from your_project_folder/grails-app/views/index.gsp.

If you create clean, new project in Grails 2.4.4 you can see it.

Of course you can always change it to your custom view. Read about [url mapping in Grails 2.4.4](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.4/guide/single.html#urlmappings).